# Focus is not working by index in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of items which have update text field with some words, I want to get the focus at end of the words on the selected index. but every time I am getting focus on last index.

Here is my HTML code

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <li ng-repeat="i in number">
    <input focus-on="focusMe" value="sfsfsf" />
    <button type="submit" ng-click="do()">do</button>
  </li>
</body>
```

Here my controller:

```
app.directive('focusOn', function() {
   return function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.$on('focusOn', function(e, name) {
        if(name === attr.focusOn) {
          elem[0].focus();
        }
      });
   };
});

app.factory('focus', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
  return function(name) {
    $timeout(function (){
      $rootScope.$broadcast('focusOn', name);
    });
  }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, focus) {
$scope.number=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  $scope.do=function(){
      focus('focusMe'); 
  }
```

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fzs2SuYJ1LgypzfKDSk8?p=preview).

Comment: Your plunker is  not about what you asked here.. check it once.

Comment: Like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/eQSnIJpGyvJ6peiIsqTp?p=preview

Comment: @abarik review PSL plunker. It is what you asked..

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/xlk2oSzqEFFTi3jtmGoL?p=preview

Comment: Both link working fine for select index but not showing at end of the words which I have given, it is important for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solution will probably depend on what browsers you need to support.

You can try this:

```
scope.$on('focusOn', function(e, name) {

  if (name == attr.name) {

    var element = elem[0];

    element.focus();

    var value = element.value;
    element.value = '';
    element.value = value;
  }
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/pulIrU56qf2J4UjCJlgQ?p=preview